# Missing Cognito user information when invoking a Lambda from API Gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway with an authorizer backed by Cognito. I have an end-point backed by a Lambda (implemented in Java) that requires the user's unique identifier.

When I test the function through the API Gateway UI the Lambda receives the user information in `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent.getRequestContext().getIdentity()`. When I invoke the function externally (from a Javascript client) this information is missing.

Does anyone know what the difference is & how I can get the user's information to be passed to the Lambda?

I have tried using a body mapping template that copies across the user information instead of using Lambda proxy integration. I've also tried swapping from accepting an ID token to an access token. These all behave as described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in [this AWS forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=777752) and [this serverless forum post](https://forum.serverless.com/t/c-lambda-get-cognito-identity/1627/3).

The user's identifier is contained in `requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub`, which isn't included in the Java object model `ProxyRequestContext`.

It's still not clear to me why the `identity` object is always (mostly) empty